Provide VulkanSDK via CMake FetchContent
I want to provide the Vulkan SDK via CMake's FetchContent module.
# Vulkan SDK
set(VULKAN_SDK_VERSION 1.3.290.0)

# FetchContent_Declare() calls
FetchContent_Declare(VulkanHeaders
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers.git
                     GIT_TAG "vulkan-sdk-${VULKAN_SDK_VERSION}"
                     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE)

FetchContent_Declare(VulkanLoader
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader.git
                     GIT_TAG "vulkan-sdk-${VULKAN_SDK_VERSION}"
                     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE)

FetchContent_Declare(VulkanUtilityLibraries
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Utility-Libraries.git
                     GIT_TAG "vulkan-sdk-${VULKAN_SDK_VERSION}"
                     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE)

FetchContent_Declare(SPIRV-Headers
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Headers.git
                     GIT_TAG "vulkan-sdk-${VULKAN_SDK_VERSION}"
                     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE)

FetchContent_Declare(SPIRV-Tools
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Tools.git
                     GIT_TAG "vulkan-sdk-${VULKAN_SDK_VERSION}"
                     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE)

FetchContent_Declare(VulkanValidationLayers
                     GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers.git
                     GIT_TAG "vulkan-sdk-${VULKAN_SDK_VERSION}"
                     OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE)

# Build Settings
set(SPIRV_SKIP_TESTS ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(USE_MIMALLOC OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(USE_ROBIN_HOOD_HASHING OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

# FetchContent_MakeAvailable() calls
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(VulkanHeaders) 
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(VulkanLoader) 
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(VulkanUtilityLibraries)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SPIRV-Headers) 
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SPIRV-Tools) 
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(VulkanValidationLayers) 

add_library(Vulkan::Vulkan INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)

target_link_libraries(Vulkan::Vulkan INTERFACE 
                      Vulkan::Headers 
                      Vulkan::Loader
                      Vulkan::LayerSettings
                      Vulkan::UtilityHeaders
                      Vulkan::SafeStruct
                      SPIRV-Headers
                      SPIRV-Tools
                      VkLayer_utils)

I link against my project.
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
                      glm::glm 
                      glfw
                      Vulkan::Vulkan)

I have simple Vulkan Hello World to check if the validation layers are available.
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers = {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
};

#ifdef NDEBUG
const bool enableValidationLayers = false;
#else
const bool enableValidationLayers = true;
#endif

void checkValidationLayerSupport() {
    uint32_t layerCount;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);

    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layerCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers.data());

    for (const char* layerName : validationLayers) {
        bool layerFound = false;

        for (const auto& layerProperties : availableLayers) {
            if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0) {
                layerFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!layerFound) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Required validation layer not found!");
        }
    }
}

VkInstance createInstance() {
    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        checkValidationLayerSupport();
    }

    VkInstance instance;
    VkInstanceCreateInfo createInfo{};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;

    if (enableValidationLayers) {
        createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = validationLayers.data();
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(validationLayers.size());
    } else {
        createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    }

    if (vkCreateInstance(&createInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Vulkan instance!");
    }

    return instance;
}

int main() {
    try {
        // GLFW initialisieren
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);

        // Vulkan Instanz erstellen
        VkInstance instance = createInstance();

        // Hier könnte dein Vulkan-Code fortgesetzt werden

        vkDestroyInstance(instance, nullptr);
    } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I get no errors at configuartion or build stage. When I run the program it states that no validation layers   are available. This is not the correct behaviour, because when I use the vanilla VulkanSDK installed and use find_package() it correctly lists all validation layers available.

The issue is that your CMake file builds the validation layer someplace in your build tree and the Vulkan Loader can't find it because your build tree is not one of the standard places it looks for layers.  One way to fix this is to set the VK_LAYER_PATH environment variable to include the directory where the validation layer binary and JSON file ended up in your build tree before launching the application.  The Loader GitHub repo should contain a document describing this behavior.

Thank you, this was exactly the problem! So the way I understand it it's no CMake Cache variable but an environmental variable. Is there an elegant way to set this environmental variable as part of the build process? For now I just hard coded it to try the proposed solution.
Tanks in advance!

Edit: For example set(ENV{VK_LAYER_PATH} "${VVL_BINARY_DIR}/layers") does not seem to work for some reason.

The build processes and the application process are different, so setting an environment variable in the build process won’t affect the application.  You might look into CMake Presets, which is a way to set various CMake parameters and cache variables for the configure, build, and test “phases”.  You should be able to specify the layer path environment variable in the test preset using the same substitution variables to locate the binary.  Then use “cmake test” to launch the application.  The VS Code CMake Tools extension handles all this pretty smoothly.
